# How to identify data attribute value from element and pair with array item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to associate items from an array with their respective parent elements whose data attribute needs to match the array string when present.

While I can log the array items, I also need to identify the parent where those attribute values exist and apply styling to those specific elements. These values may or may not be present and I therefore need to loop through each element to find the data attr and value.

```
<div class="rateBucket" data-rate-code="some-rate-code-value"></div>

const rateCodes = ["IK2KB","IK3KB", "IK550"];

let rateContainerArray = document.querySelectorAll('div.rateContainer[data-rate-code]'); // This element will contain the desired attribute value

rateCodes.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    console.log(item, index); // prints the array
    // do something like add a class to parent element
    // or wrap all children into a single parent DIV (i.e. rateContainerArray )
});
```

As stated above, once the array has a div associated with it, I want to add a class or maybe wrap all elements within a single DIV, for example.

Comment: why don't you use `rateContainerArray = document.getElementsByClassName("rateContainer")` and then access the dataset in the array items directly like `rateContainerArray.forEach((item, index) => { // do something with item.dataset.rateCodeValue});` More info on accessing data attributes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Thank you @IskandarRezaRazali. I actually considered this. However, I think the problem would be, there will be other rate codes not included in my array. I only want/need the ones in the array--which is shortened in this example. The others will be ignored. I neglected to mention this in my post.

Wouldn't using the dataset expose all data attribute values? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The `.dataset` HTMLElement property will contain all `data-*` attributes of the element in context. You could do a check just before processing the item in the forEach so that it only continues if the value is contained in your `rateCodes` array. So you could do a check like this: `if (rateCodes.indexOf(item.dataset.rateCodeValue === -1)){ return; }` so that it will skip the values that don't match. Check out this article for more info on the `.indexOf()` method for arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Hello @IskandarRezaRazali. Thank you again for your help! I ended up doing the following, which works as expected: